# How to increase permissions for a Facebook user that has already authorized your application?

Tags: facebook

If a user has already authorized my application, but I would like to request additional permissions from the user, how can I do this?

The reason I ask is because I would like to handle authorization with the relatively new Facebook Registration plugin:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration

However, the plugin doesn't appear to provide any way for me to request any permissions beyond the basic, and so later when additional permission are needed, I would like to request the user to increase the permissions granted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by the Facebook Administrator on their [forums](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=308823), this is not supported:

> For the moment you can't ask for
>   extended permissions in the
>   registration plugin so you have to ask
>   them on your redirect_uri. Please,
>   file a bug for this issue in bugzilla
>   and select the tag "wishlist" (or
>   subscribe to an existing bug and add
>   your information to it). Best practice
>   is to link back to the bug in the
>   originating forum thread to help
>   fellow developers and Facebook
>   engineers track the conversation and
>   provide follow-up.

I've found a related [ticket](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14733) that is filed on their Bug tracking system, you need to vote to raise it to Facebook development team.

**EDIT:**
How to ask for extra permissions can be found on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions/4936270#4936270).

Comment: So it is possible to request increased permissions after the registration it sounds like, since they suggest doing so on the redirect_uri. Any ideas on how you'd do that?

Comment: @William Jones: I suppose they mean doing the same on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions/4936270#4936270). Please consider accepting the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your original answer so that it addresses the original question? I don't think I'm supposed to accept an answer when the real answer is in the comments.

Comment: @William Jones: Edited. Please note that my original answer satisfies your question anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be old. But I face the same problem and I have been here.

I was quite disappointed but later I solved my problem i.e. to ask additional permission for already authenticated user, i did the following

```
$params = array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => "SELECT user_likes FROM permissions WHERE uid=me()",
);
$result = $facebook->api($params);
$likes_permission=$result[0][user_likes];
if($likes_permission!=1)
    echo "<script>window.top.location='".$loginUrl."';</script>";
```