# Get user approved permissions in facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

After I add a permission, the user has to remove the app and add it again, in order to grant new permission. The weird thing is that when I request a permission that the user hasn't approved, I don't get an error, but rather only an empty result set.

How do I check if the user approved a permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Apps: Additional permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions)

Comment: The answer I posted above should answer your question. But just wanted to add a note.. **USER DOESN'T HAVE TO REMOVE YOUR APPLICATION TO ADD EXTRA PERMISSIONS!**

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple as you can just use the openn graph API to get that information

https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=....