# How do I ask for facebook permissions in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

How do I ask for facebook permissions in PHP? can you please give me an example?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the user's `access_token`(which you can get via `$facebook->getAccessToken()` after you've logged a user in:

```
try{
    $permissions = $facebook->api('/me/permissions', 'get', array('access_token'=>$access_token));
    print_r($permissions, true);
    if(empty($permissions['data'][0]['installed'])){
        echo 'User has not installed the application.';
    }
    if(empty($permissions['data'][0]['publish_stream'])){
        echo 'User does not have the publish_stream permission.';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are new to the Facebook API, I suggest you the following:

1. Start reading the [Facebook Developers Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/).
2. **Download** the [Facebook PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/), there's an [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) file too..just [create your application](http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php), insert your app_id and app_secret and you are good to go. (***It's highly recommended that you use the PHP-SDK***)
3. To ask for permissions, you can do the following:

   `<fb:login-button scope="read_stream"></fb:login-button>`
   More about this can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions/4936270#4936270) too.
4. You can test all of the above locally, and here's a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-develop-your-facebook-application-locally/6/) that I wrote about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you request permissions.. To detect if a user is authorized with your app or not, etc you have to use the Facebook PHP library, that is much more complicated, read here to get started: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Just for requesting permission you first need to have your fb-root div and include the Facebook Javascript Graph API file, then put a login button.. The autologoutlink parameter specifies if it should show "Logout" if the user is already connected to your application.

The perms is the permissions requested for the app, a full list is on the Facebook developer docs site.. You have to enter your application ID also.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday" size="large" onlogin="window.location = '/';">Connect to this application using Facebook</fb:login-button>
</div>
    <script>
      FB.init({appId: 'ENTER YOUR APPLICATION ID HERE', status: true,
               cookie: true, xfbml: true});
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    </script>
```