# Add Facebook status feed to profile page of site members

Tags: php, facebook

I have a Digg style site, currently each member has a profile page where they add links to their projects and social networking profiles.

I am trying to implement a feature that allows the member to display the last "X" number of status updates to their Facebook wall.

I have been going through the Facebook API FAQs, but unclear on how to best implement this.

Does anyone know a good starting point for writing the API call or where I should look for examples?

My site currently runs on PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ask for facebook permissions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050201/how-do-i-ask-for-facebook-permissions-in-php)

Comment: Also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/facebook-sharing-graph-api/4816134#4816134) is worth reading.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I just want to allow my members to enter their Facebook ID into a field I will save in my database, then when their profile page on my site is visited, have a script call to facebook using the stored Facebook ID get the last 5 wall posts of given user.

Comment: Ah, you need to read not publish, okay I'm going to answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a set of point to get you started:

1. [Create an application](http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php)
2. Download the [Facebook PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)
3. Acquire the `read_stream,offline_access` permissions (more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050201/how-do-i-ask-for-facebook-permissions-in-php/5051237#5051237))
4. Save the user id AND the `access_token` to your DB.
5. Next time you want to retrieve the user's wall posts use:

   ```
   $feed = $facebook->api("/PROFILE_ID/feed", "GET", array("access_token" => "XXXX"));
   ```
6. Always try your Facebook application locally before implementing it on a live website (see link on point 3).