# How can i get an extended permission form an existing user in facebook application

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

i am developing a facebook application.now i need to get more permission form user like user_birthday. is it possible to get these permissions from an existing user who has already added this application. or is it possible to ask them these permissions again?
 anyone please help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Apps: Additional permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are using the graph api then you can follow these steps after creating the object of facebook

```
//Facebook Authentication part
    $session = $facebook->getSession();
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
            'canvas'    => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 0,
            'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday, user_location,user_work_history'
            )
    );

    $fbme = null;

    if (!$session) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
    else {
        try {
            $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
            $fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me');

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Add new permission in 'req_perms' parameter It will automatically redirect user to get new permissions 
You can check the related tutorial here http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/