# Requesting the stream_tag table

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

i'm trying to request the stream_tag facebook table with the php api for an application

```
SELECT post_id,actor_id, target_id
FROM stream_tag 
WHERE target_id= me()
```

It only get me 10 results. How can i get really **all** results?

i got all this permission :

```
email
user_about_me
user_birthday
user_hometown
user_location
user_status
friends_about_me
friends_status

read_stream
read_insights
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FQL solution**

There are 2 possible reasons for the issue I can think of, without access to the actual data:

First reason: You need to add permissions. Specifically:

```
friends_photo_video_tags
user_photo_video_tags
```

You may also need permissions for the objects that are tagged inside posts. The "read stream" permission grants access to a wall post's tags but it is not clear from the documentation if it grants access to the tags of the object a post holds as a field, e.g. the tags in a photo in a post.

The following objects can have tags, in addition to the Post object:

Checkins. Permissions needed:

```
user_checkins
friends_checkins
```

Photo. Permissions needed:

```
user_photos
friends_photos
```

Video. Permissions needed

```
user_videos
friends_videos
```

Second reason: You are experiencing a bug/inconsistency in the stream_tag table. There are inconsistencies with this table reported in the Facebook developer pages, based on tests run by developers. These include:

- For two status updates from the same user with tagged users, the stream_tag table returns tagging information correctly for one update but returns no information for the second.
- The stream_tag table doesn't include tags from notes and link comments.

[Here](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL%3astream_tag) is a FBDevWiki summary of reported issues with the stream_tag table, under the heading "Notes/Bugs/Gotchas".

**Graph API solution**

If adding the above permissions don't help with the FQL query, you can instead call the Graph API 'tagged' connection like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/tagged
```

which returns tags in posts, photos and videos for the user.

Comment: i can't ask for these two permissions :
friends_photo_video_tags
user_photo_video_tags

it's doesn't exist from the interface.
I'm trying with the others

Comment: You can find the complete permissions list in the Graph Explorer here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. Click the 'get Access Token' button to see the two _photo_video_tags permissions listed. Note the Graph Explorer list just mentioned includes more permissions than the official API here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: those perms are just not selectable (as you can see here, http://screencast.com/t/YyVdr6F3Flt)
do you think it will change something? i ever got 10 results so if i haven't the good perms, they will not gave me results?

Comment: You could do the permissions request in code: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions/4936270#4936270.

Comment: i'm really sure i've been tagged more than 10 times! ;)

for the first solution, just looking for the tag on a post for the moment (not video/photo/other, i'll see that after) 

for the second, i try to use limit, but i doesn't work.
i'm lost on it... so sad !

Comment: I've edited my post with a summary of known bugs/inconsistencies with the stream_tag table, and a Graph API solution. –

Comment: Ok ok, i'll see that. It's not the answer what i was waiting but ^^ thanks a lot !