# Get all photos the user is tagged in on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to fetch all the images I'm tagged in on Facebook.

It's working almost as it should, I just got one problem.

If I'm tagged in the post, but not tagged on the image, it doesn't show up in the output.

Any ideas why?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT pid, src_big, link, album_object_id, object_id, place_id, aid, created 
  FROM photo 
 WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid, object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On-picture tags are not the same as tags in the description (post).

There are three FQL tables to get the content where a user has been tagged:

- [`photo_tag`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/) to get tags on photos,
- [`stream_tag`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_tag/) to get tags on **posts**,
- [`video_tag`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video_tag) to get tags on videos.

You used the first one but you also need the second one. Similarly to your photo tags request, you will then have to use the `stream` table.

Comment: Any idea of how I can get all streams I'm tagged in my others or by myself?
I've tried with this, but without luck:

SELECT actor_id, post_id FROM stream_tag WHERE target_id = me() LIMIT 1000

Comment: That query looks right, but it [only gives me 9 results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173488/requesting-the-stream-tag-table). Don't forget the `read_stream` permission.

Comment: I've that permission already. Maybe some inner join function should be used instead to merge two tables? Or what do you think would be the best solution?