# facebook post to wall - works only if permission already available, how can i ask user for permission?

Tags: php, python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Apps: Additional permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions)

Facebook post to wall :

I can post to wall by sending post request like this or using some language specific code.

```
 curl -F "access_token=tokenstring" -F "message=some message here" "http://graph.facebook.com/username/feed"
```

The above works only if the  user has already given permission for PUBLISH_STREAM. But what if the app didnt have the permission from the user already ? How can I ask the user for the permission ?

Even while asking the access_token from this url

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=" SECRET " &client_secret=" SECRET "&scope=publish_stream
```

it is giving me access token without asking permission from the user, and while using this access token, it is giving error that the user didnt give access to the app, is there a way that i can redirect the user asking the permission. or some box asking for permission ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes according to Facebook user permission you should first generate token.
and user will give you permission then you can post his/her wall...

Comment: Yeah, just tell me how can i get the permission ?

Comment: Check this

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=100001665994667%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

Comment: I mean, programatically how can i get ?

Comment: Have you had a look into the docs at all …? Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/