# Collecting wall posting permission when using the Facebook Registration plugin

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to collect wall posting permission when using the Facebook Registration plugin? I don't see it on the docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase permissions for a Facebook user that has already authorized your application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812774/how-to-increase-permissions-for-a-facebook-user-that-has-already-authorized-your)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to collect wall posting permission.(facebook didn't gave any option for this in registration plugin)