# Facebook Registration Plugin - How to set Advanced Permissions? Offline Access etc?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the FB Registration plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/

What I can't figure out is how to you set adv permissions for access like offline permission, post to the wall etc?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase permissions for a Facebook user that has already authorized your application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812774/how-to-increase-permissions-for-a-facebook-user-that-has-already-authorized-your)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least, not yet. The registration plugin doesn't have any options for permission requests- which unfortunately makes it totally useless for me, and I'm sure many other people.